# Unwanted horizontal scroll bar in the documentation tour page

Tags: bug, documentation, design

There is a horizontal scroll bar in the bottom of the [Documentation Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) page.

There is no use of the scroll bar in my screen resolution `1600 x 900`.

Comment: I can't see any horizontal scrollbar in my 1024px wide android tablet screen using Chrome.

Comment: I can see it - using 1920x1080 on desktop Chrome.

Comment: It's there with SeaMonkey running at 2560 pixels wide.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to reproduce this as well.

The reason for the scrollbar is due to the id="content" element having a padding that it gets from main (as in the main page of Stack Overflow, all.css), **in addition** to that element also having a 100% width. The result is a slight horizontal scroll.

This is the padding definition:

```
.so-header~.container #content {
    padding: 24px 15px;
}
```

There are several ways to fix this, I am sure they will chose the one most in line with their design approaches.

In the meantime, if you are running a user script or some sort of styling, you can just override this rule for the docs page and be done with it. Otherwise, at least it is only on a minor page and shouldn't cause that much strain... Really, who is repeatedly viewing the Docs tour page? :)

Comment: "Who is repeatedly viewing the Docs tour page?" Well, everyone now checking out the scroll bar, and others creating their user scripts.